# Incompatitibility javascript error with php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I hava an error javascript. This javascript create a dynamic table add and remove.

In reality, the script is correct and work perfetly but, inside my tools I hava a function than create a problem with this javascript and I want know if it's possible to modify this javascript.

The problem come from this element who create a dropdown `(HTML::selectMenu`)

```
<td class='col-md-2'><?php echo HTML::selectMenu('suppliers_id[["+i+"]', $OSCOM_ProductsAdmin->SupplierDropDown()); ?>
```

I have this function than can't touch else this site does'nt work.

```
public static function output($string, $translate = null) {
  if (!isset($translate)) {
    $translate = ['"' => '&quot;'];
  }

      return strtr(trim($string), $translate);
    }
```

inside the the html `HTML::selectMenu` function (dropdown) I have inside

```
$field = '<select name="' . static::output($name) . '"';
```

When I edit my htmlpage generated this code become

```
<select name="suppliers_id[[&quot;+i+&quot;]" id="suppliers_id[[&quot;+i+&quot;]" class="form-control"><option value="">--Aucun--</option><option value="1">test</option></select>
```

and the problem come here : `[&quot;+i+&quot;]` and must be `['+i+']` (like the javascript)

How to resolve the problem ?

Thank you

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=<?php echo $id-1; ?>;
      $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td>" +

          "<td class='col-md-2'><input name='id["+i+"]' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control'  /> </td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo HTML::selectMenu('suppliers_id[["+i+"]', $OSCOM_ProductsAdmin->SupplierDropDown()); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><input  name='discount_quantity["+i+"]' type='text' placeholder='Qty'  class='form-control'></td><td class='col-md-2'><input  name='discount_supplier_price["+i+"]' type='text' placeholder='Supplier Price'  class='form-control'></td><td class='col-md-2'><input  name='discount_customer["+i+"]' type='text' placeholder='Without %' class='form-control'></td>");


        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
      });
      $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i>1){
          $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
          i--;
        }
      });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have an argument to override the translating, so just do `static::output($name, array())`

Comment: sorry I don't understant

Comment: Your question is not clear completely, but why can't you try escaping the quote character like `$translate = ['"' => '\''];`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you need to even apply that `output()` method in the firstplace. All it's doing is adding the quote replacement that you don't want, so:

1) Don't even apply that method:

```
$field = '<select name="'.$name.'"';
```

2) If that method is not the full method and it does more that you aren't showing or it's in a function/method at a higher level that you can't modify, then just convert the output using `htmlspecialchars_decode($str,ENT_QUOTES)`:

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(addslashes('<select name="suppliers_id[&quot;+i+&quot;]" id="suppliers_id[&quot;+i+&quot;]" class="form-control"><option value="">--Aucun--</option><option value="1">test</option></select>'), ENT_QUOTES);
```

You may have to use `addslashes()` before hand, then decode.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution including `str_replace`

```
                <div><a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete Row</a><br /><br/></div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=<?php echo $new_id; ?>;
      $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"<?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::hiddenField('id["+i+"]', "+i+")); ?></td>" +
          "<td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::selectMenu('suppliers_id["+i+"]', $OSCOM_ProductsAdmin->SupplierDropDown())); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::selectMenu('customers_group_id["+i+"]', B2BAdmin::getCustomersGroup('Normal'))); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::inputField('discount_quantity["+i+"]', '', 'placeholder="Qty"')); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::inputField('discount_supplier_price["+i+"]', '', 'placeholder="Supplier Price"')); ?></td><td class='col-md-2'><?php echo  str_replace('"', '\'', HTML::inputField('discount_customer["+i+"]', '', 'placeholder="Without %"')); ?></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
      });
      $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i>1){
          $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
          i--;
        }
      });

    });
</script>
```